# Callback function: Incompatible argument

Tags: c++, callback

I am trying to use callback function in my problem but I got into some troubles. In the `sort()` function, the parameter `&compareType` has an error:

> Argument of type "bool (Person::*)(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)" is incompatible with parameter of type "compare"`

person.h

```
class Person
{
public:
    bool compareType(const Person& p1, const Person& p2) { return ... };
    void sort()
    {
        ...    
        list->addInOrder(person, &compareType);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

dlinkedlist.h

```
typedef bool (*compare)(const Person& p1, const Person&p2);
class dlinkedlist
{
public:
    void addInOrder(const Person& person, compare comparefunc)
    {
        Person person2;
        ...
        comparefunc(person, person2);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `static` to the compare function.

Comment: Make the compare function a `static` member function: `static bool compareType(const Person& p1, const Person& p2) { return ... };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool compareType(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
```

is actually of type

```
bool (Person::*) (const Person&, const Person&)
```

You have to make your method `static` to have correct type.

Answer (score 3):

There are mainly three solutions.

You can either:

- declare the member method as `static`
- define a function outside the class that is `friend` of your class (if needed) and use it

The third solution is maybe the most interesting one:

- you can use a non-capturing lambda function that, because of the fact that is a non-capturing one, can decay to a pointer to function.

So, as an example, the following lambda is perfectly fine in your case:

```
[](const Person& p1, const Person& p2) { return true; }
```

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
struct A { };

using Fn = bool(*)(const A &, const A &);

void f(Fn fn) {
    fn(A{}, A{});
};

int main() {
    f([](const A &, const A &){ return true; });
};
```

As you can see, the lambda automatically decays to a pointer to function, so it's fine to use it in such a case.
Obviously, the solution involving the lambda is not suitable if you need to access private members, of course.

Answer (score 1):

A non-static method is different to a free function or static method. You can see that from the type in the error message:

```
bool (Person::*)(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
```

which is different from the type of a simple function

```
bool (*)(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
```

(intuitively, the non-static method has to somehow get a `this` pointer, so the compiler has to do something different when calling it).

---

Note that your `compareType` shouldn't be a non-static member anyway - you'd have to call it like

```
personA.compareType(personB, personC)
```

which doesn't make much sense.

---

Either make it a static method (so you don't invoke it on an instance of Person)

```
class Person {
  public:
    static bool compareType(const Person&, const Person&);
    // ...
};
```

or just make it a free function

```
bool comparePeople(const Person&, const Person&);
```

Answer (score -1):

Non static class method implicitly adds reference to this, so your function actually looks like

```
bool compareType(Person *this, const Person &p1, const Person &p2);
```

You should declare it as static, and this will not be passed into.

Comment: @SergeyA Maybe you should explain your opinion?

Comment: @There is nothing to explain. There is nothing in the standard which says this function looks like it. Instead, it says that function looks like `bool (Person::*)(const Person&, const Person&);`